# sql selecting records from table containing similar data but distinctly identified by a single field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains indexed fields. Could someone help me with an appropriate select statement? This table is kind of like an audit log. When data for a record is changed, a new record is created with up-to-date data, and the current timestamp when that new record is created. I would like to query the most recent entries for a given criteria.

for example:

| Base | Additive | Group | Bulk | Distance | LastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aloe | Beef | 1 | 910 | 90 | 2023-02-01 06:00:00 |
| Aloe | Mutton | 2 | 467 | 533 | 2023-02-01 06:00:00 |
| Beef | Aloe | 1 | 912 | 90 | 2023-02-01 06:00:00 |
| Aloe | Beef | 1 | 912 | 90 | 2023-02-03 07:00:00 |

In this data, Base and Additive are the indexed fields (no primary key), and there may be multiple records for the pair but distinctly different by the LastUpdated field. I would like my select query to return the last 2 rows in this case as the criteria I would want to supply would be the group number.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you're trying to get the latest row per `Group`. You can achieve this by enumerating the rows with a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), within the partition of the `Group` field, and sorted by the `LastUpdated` field descending like so:

```
DECLARE @GroupFilter INT = 1;

WITH _LatestLogs AS
(
    SELECT 
        Base,
        Additive,
        [Group],
        Bulk,
        Distance,
        LastUpdated,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Base, Additive, [Group] ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) AS SortId
    FROM Logs
    WHERE Group = @GroupFilter
)

SELECT 
    Base,
    Additive,
    [Group],
    Bulk,
    Distance,
    LastUpdated
FROM _LatestLogs
WHERE SortId = 1;
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. It only returns one entry per group. I want to return the latest of all entries in a given group.

Comment: @WalterZydhek "*It only returns one entry per group. I want to return the latest of all entries in a given group.*" - Can you please clarify the difference?...perhaps by providing an expected output example in your post. "*I want to return the latest*" typically means 1.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough. The example data I show was just a few rows of al the data. I specified I wanted to return the last 2 rows of this data (as shown). Notice both are in group 1, and the 4th row is newer than the first row. Thus, both those last 2 rows should be returned. The 1st row is ignored because it is older than the 4th row, and the 2nd row is ignored because it is not in group 1.

Comment: @WalterZydhek But the 1st row and 3rd row have the same `LastUpdated` date, so why is the 3rd row returned when the 1st one is not?...is it because the `Base` and `Additive` in row 3 are different from row 4? Would my understanding be correct to say you're looking for the latest row of each combination of `Base, Additive` for a specific `Group` at a time?

Comment: I believe that is a fair understanding.

Comment: @WalterZydhek I've updated my query, give that a go and let me know either way. The *magic* is in the definition of the `PARTITION` clause to determine how you want to group (not to be confused with your `Group` column) things together (in this case by `Base, Additive`) to then select the latest row from each grouping. I did leave the `Group` column as part of the `PARTITION` clause too in case you ever want to look at multiple or all `Groups` of the data at the same time.

Comment: Ahh! That works. Thank you